# Find duplicate value in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, object

Given the following object:

```
answers = {'a': 3,'b': 2,'c': 3, 'd': 1};
```

How can I find whether or not there is a duplicate value? I need to write a condition that will say if two of these have the same value, then `console.log('duplicate values found')`.

Comment: Objects can't have duplicate keys.

Comment: Yes, I am aware. I'm looking for a test that will return whether or not there are duplicate values in there.

Comment: Can the values themselves be objects etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write a nested loop to find that,

```
var keys = Object.keys(answers);
var dupe = false;

for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
 for(var j=i+1;j<keys.length;j++){
   if(answers[keys[i]] === answers[keys[j]]){
     dupe = true;
     break;
   }
 }
 if(dupe){ console.log("dupe value is there.."); break; }
}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/u47px6e0/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean duplicate values and not duplicate key/value pairs. This is how I'd do it:

```
function findDuplicateValues(input) {
    var values = {},
        key;

    for (key in input) {
        if (input.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            values[input[key]] = values.hasOwnProperty(input[key]) ? values[input[key]] + 1 : 1;
        }
    }

    for (key in values) {
        if (values.hasOwnProperty(key) && values[key] > 1) {
            console.log('duplicate values found');
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

For large objects it will be quicker than the previous answer, because there are no nested loops (this will execute in linear O(n) time rather than quadratic O(n<sup>2</sup>) time).

Comment: This won't work if the values are objects. Anyway, why don't you just issue the message and return the minute you find the second one?