# How to push out an array from a set if text is the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Say I have an array:

```
setArray = [{index: 1, answer: 'test'}, 
            {index: 2, answer: 'another test'}, 
            {index: 3, answer: 'test'}];
```

Without doing a long winded if else statement going through each like:

```
if(setArray[0].answer == setArray[1].answer){
 // do this
}
if(setArray[1].answer == setArray[2].answer){
 // do this
}
```

Is there a way to do a statement that would look at each of the 3 texts and compare them that if they match exactly, would remove each array that matches into a new array ( for validation purposes ). It would be like:

```
var makeArray = [];
if( //check each array){        
    makeArray.push(// arrays that match);
}
```

Comment: you can `loop` through your `array` to check the condition for each element.

Comment: You could use 2 for loops, and iterate over the array checking for equality, there also is .filter() which may be of use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find duplicate value in JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754518/find-duplicate-value-in-javascript-object)

Comment: *"if they match exactly, could remove them into a new array ( for validation purposes )."*  Do you mean both of them are removed from the original array, or only one?  If only one, which one gets removed?

Comment: yeah thats the problem, if i remove them both then i can't see if the other value that hasn't been tested matches any of the removed ones

Comment: So do you want all of the duplicates removed?

Comment: yes so i can use that new array to bind to a statement

Comment: what is your expected output? please edit your question and put it

Comment: i had updated it, "would remove each array that matches into a new array"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like this? Loop through both arrays.

```js
var setArray = [{index: 1, answer: 'test'}, 
            {index: 2, answer: 'another test'}, 
            {index: 3, answer: 'test'}];
var newArray = [];
            
        
            
for (var i = 0; i < setArray.length; i++) {
  var duplicate = false;
  for (var j = 0; j < setArray.length; j++) {
    if (setArray[i].answer == setArray[j].answer && (i != j) ) {
      duplicate = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (duplicate) {
    newArray.push(setArray[i]);
  }
}

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: this just pushes out a matching array, not each array that matches

Comment: Oh you want both of them? Please specify the required output

Comment: Is this the correct output? `[
  {
    "index": 1,
    "answer": "test"
  },{
    "index": 3,
    "answer": "test"
  },
]`

Comment: @Keith Done :) Hope it helped

Comment: yes this is what i was looking for thanks! just couldn't figure out a good way to do a loop. Didn't think to loop through 2 different loops

Comment: That'd be a costly approach O(n^2)

Comment: @SivcanSingh I agree, but I don't think there is any other faster way.. If you do have a faster way please tell me.

Comment: Sure! I'll put it as an answer

Comment: @SheshankS. I've put it up, you can take a look

Comment: @Keith You can see if my answer solves your use-case :)

Answer (score 1):

Using two for loops:

```
var makeArray = [];

for(let i = 0; i < setArray.length; i++){
    for(let j = i + 1; j < setArray.length; j++){
        if(setArray[i].answer === setArray[j].answer){
           //We have a match on the answer property, push into new array
           makeArray.push(setArray[i]);
           break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you even test this code before writing it?
Just look at it and see how you are not handling the corner cases where your internal loop goes beyond the length and ends up ignoring the LAST value of the array.

Comment: @SivcanSingh My answer gives the same results as the accepted answer, so if the results of the accepted answer are not what the OP wants, I will be happy to modify this.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var setArray = [{
    index: 1,
    answer: 'test'
  },
  {
    index: 2,
    answer: 'another test'
  },
  {
    index: 3,
    answer: 'test'
  },
  {
    index: 4,
    answer: 'test three'
  },
  {
    index: 5,
    answer: 'test'
  }
];
var duplicateArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < setArray.length; i++) {
  //find all the elements with the same answer
  var duplicates = setArray.filter(function(element){
    return element.answer === setArray[i].answer;
  });
  
  if (duplicates.length > 1) {
    //if there are more than one, remove them all to the duplicate array
    duplicates.forEach(function(duplicate){
      duplicateArray.push(duplicate);
      setArray.splice(setArray.indexOf(duplicate), 1);
    });
  }
}
  
console.log(setArray);
console.log(duplicateArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a simple hash map!

```
let setArray = [
        {index: 1, answer: 'test'}, 
        {index: 2, answer: 'another test'}, 
        {index: 3, answer: 'test'}
    ],
    hash = {};

setArray.map((o) => !hash[o.answer] ? hash[o.answer] = [o] : hash[o.answer].push(o));

console.log(hash['another test']); 
console.log(hash['test']);
```

This makes sure that you're doing it in O(n) and accessing the value from a hash takes O(1).

Comment: I can look at this tomorrow ( as I have the project closed ), but I will be sure to test this. Thanks for working on it

Comment: Yes but it takes more memory.

Comment: @SheshankS. How exactly is this taking more memory? The space complexity will still be O(n) - You're just breaking the big array into small ones with a little overhead.

Nothing heavy, but it's extremely fast and concise. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
setArray.forEach(function(elementA, indexA) {
  setArray.forEach(function(elementB, indexB) {
    if (indexA == indexB) {
      continue; // We don't want to test current element against itself
    }
    if (elementA.answer == elementB.answer) {
      // arrays that match
      // You'll probably have to unset the matching elements so no duplicated matches are added in the next iterations
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: using foreach is bad practice